# Smartmirror: i2cdetect and voltage

Tags: pi-3, voltage

I build my first smartmirror and I have two issues.

First of all this is my setup:

- RASPBERRY PI 3 Model B
- [LG-Philips LP173WF1 (TL)(B2) 17,3" LED Display Screen (non-glossy) Full HD](https://www.amazon.de/Display-non-glossy-LP173WF1-TL-B2/dp/B00KL8B4XS/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1456055153&sr=1-1&keywords=B00KL8B4XS&tag=glancr-21)
- [Hdmi Controller](https://www.ebay.de/c/1055841231)
- [Ktec Universal AC DC Netzteil 12V 3A](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00JINQPJA/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=glancr-21&linkId=e89a42c951281887e0659ecf7c1c3d59)

**1. Issue Display Turns On/Off**
The mirror works fine, but the display turns on and off sometimes. But just the display, not the Raspberry Pi. So I guess maybe the voltage is to low. Also in the bash i get the message that the voltage is to low. So, what can you recommand? Maybe the offical one? ;)

**2. Issue Witty Pi Mini i2cDetect**
I would like to use this controller to start the pi in the morning and shutdown in the evening.
So I tried to add this [Witty Pi Mini](http://www.uugear.com/product/wittypi-mini/), but if I try to add this i2cdetect -y 0 or 1 does not recognized anything.

I follow the steps in the official [manuell](https://www.uugear.com/doc/WittyPiMini_UserManual.pdf), but I still don't find a way to solve it.
Could it be possible that it is also a voltage issue?

Thank you very much. Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: please ask only one question ... you already answered your own question #1

Comment: okay, but why?
I don't answer the first one, I asked for your opinion. The issues maybe correlate (I only guess).